# Explain the CEILING function for dates

Tags: excel, date

I have a formula which gives me different dates depending on the multiplier. I am not sure how it works though, except that it rounds a date. The formula is the following:
=DATE(YEAR($L$4),CEILING(MONTH($L$4),2),0)

So imagine today´s date is 18/08/2015 in cell L4. If i change the multiplier i get the following results:
=DATE(YEAR($L$4),CEILING(MONTH($L$4),2),0) = 31/07/2015

=DATE(YEAR($L$4),CEILING(MONTH($L$4),3),0) = 31/08/2015

=DATE(YEAR($L$4),CEILING(MONTH($L$4),4),0) = back again to 31/07/2015.

Why does this happen? Why does it go back to 31/07/2015 if the multiplier increases to 4?

Answer (score 2):

=CEILING('number', 'multiple') returns a multiple of the 'multiple' that is nearest to the 'number'.

Since MONTH evaluates to 8 or August, you would have =CEILING(8, 3), which evaluates to 9, because 9 is the multiple of 3 closest to 8. 2 and 4 as multiples will both return 8.

=DATE(2015, 9, 0) will return the last date of the previous month, because the day is 0.

If you tried your formula with CEILING(MONTH($L$4), 10), you would get 31/9/2015, because the multiple of 10 nearest to 8 is 10, and the DATE formula will end up looking like =DATE(2015, 10, 0) which evaluates to 31/9/2015.

As a side note, the button below is very helpful in analyzing the formulas that you select in the excel chart.
[image]